# How to fix the error : your application id may be incorrect. If the error persists, contact support@algolia.com

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I want to send cloud firestore data to algolia to enable full-text search. Firebase cloud function log is showing an error about application id. I am not able to understand this error and how to fix this.

```sh
 name: 'RetryError',
  message: 'Unreachable hosts - your application id may be incorrect. If the error persists, contact support@algolia.com.'
```

This is my index.js file

```js
exports.addFirestoreDataToAlgolia = 
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var arr = [];
  admin.firestore().collection("tags").get()
  .then((docs) => {
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
      let user = doc.data();
      user.objectID = doc.id;
      arr.push(user);
    })
    const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
    return index.saveObjects(arr, (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500);
      }
      else {
        res.status(200).send(content);
      }
    })
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
})
```

Comment: Do you have a correct value for `ALGOLIA_ID`, `ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY`, etc.??

Comment: yes I am using those values correctly still I am getting this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outbound requests (outside of Google services) can only be made from functions on a paid plan (https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Reason for the wrong appID error is that the Algolia is trying to resolve a dns using your appID, which fails. See https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript/issues/587#issuecomment-407397688

You have to move off of the free Spark plan in order to call out to Algolia from your function..

Comment: I am using Blaze plan for firebase and using algolia Paid account but my issue is still there same error App id may not be correct and everything is perfect App id , Admin api key and also function works locally perfect but when using cloud function this throws error what's the exact issue anybosy can help ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem - works on local machine, but when using it as a cloud functions it fails. Did you find a solution?
Also on a paid plan (Blaze).

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue. I'm on the blaze plan and I noticed this error occurring occasionally in my logs in the last month or so. Have about 5000 records across two indices

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error with NextJS, it was working fine with react but then when I moved to NextJs I got the error.
Turns out it was my .env variables that were not being passed correctly to the client/browser. Renaming the variables from `REACT_APP_<variable name>` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_<variable name>` to make them available to the browser as per the [NextJs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) fixed the issue.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_APP_ID=xxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_ADMIN_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```